# Create array from one field in a set of objects in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
@ride.passengers
```

Gives me something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": null,
    "salutation": "Sr",
    "first_name": "fsd",
    "last_name": "sfd",
    "email": "sf@sdf.sdf",
    "mobile": "123234345",
    "company_id": 7,
    "cost_center_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "salutation": null,
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "email": null,
    "mobile": null,
    "company_id": 12,
    "cost_center_id": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

I want to create an array with all company_ids:

```
[7,12]
```

I tried:

```
@ride.passengers.pluck(:company_id)
```

But this returns an empty error.

Comment: That looks like json in that array. It needs to be a hash.

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` is an active record method. You are trying to manipulate the data returned from an active record query, try

```
@rides.passengers.map{ |object| object["company_id"} }
```